# Azure Analysis Services Server Using Much More Memory Than Model Size?

Tags: azure, powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

We have an Azure SSAS Server with 5 models which total ~5GB of data. The Azure portal usually says we're using ~10GB of memory basically all the time. Today, that 10GB has skyrocketed up to roughly ~22GB (our cap is 25GB). I've tried restarting it, looking at the profiler, don't really see anything happening.

Also if I query the memory usage using the query below, it shows 16GB.

```
select cast((cast(sum(OBJECT_MEMORY_SHRINKABLE) + sum(OBJECT_MEMORY_NONSHRINKABLE) as numeric(14,2))/1024/1024/1024) as numeric(14,2)) from openquery([OurLinkedServer],'SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_OBJECT_MEMORY_USAGE')
```

So 3 questions:

1. How do I get the memory usage down from 23GB back to 10GB?
2. Why does the query above show 16GB but the Azure Portal shows 23GB?
3. Why do models totally 5GB eat up 10GB of memory at all times (even when it's working correctly and it's at a time when nobody is using it)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy or process a model, it creates a separate copy and then cuts over to it when it's done. All of the SSAS doc (sorry, no link, but search on it) tells you to size the capacity to 2.5 times the data size. You will live in a world of hurt if you try to size the memory smaller. You also want some extra capacity for growth. Memory is the primary constraint on SSAS performance. Don't skimp.

There are reports you can run to look at memory usage by column in your model. The easiest way is from DAX Studio (**Advanced > View Metrics**).

[image: View Metrics from DAX Studio]

High cardinality columns will consume the most memory. Separating Date and Time is an easy way to reduce cardinality. Even better yet to remove Time if you don't need it. SSAS compresses data using run length encoding. This means A A A B B B will compress way better than A B A B A B. Changing the sort order of the table can have drastic impact on the memory consumed.